# How to open a page in the dashboard without using dashboard.config

Tags: umbraco

In an Umbraco site I'm working on, I have a requirement where I need to do the following:

In the "Members" area in Umbraco, there are three content tree nodes:

- Members
- Member Groups
- Member Types

When the user clicks on any of the above nodes, the default behaviour is the following:

```
javascript.UmbClientMgr.appActions().openDashboard('member');
```

What I'd like to do is this - when the user clicks on the `Member Groups` node I want to open a new page in the dashboard (not the `members` dashboard page as configured in `dashboard.config`)

I've seen references to

```
UmbClientMgr.contentFrame('page.aspx');
```

in order to open pages in the dashboard, but I can't see how to change the default behaviour of the "Member Groups" node. I've tried editing the record for that node in `umbracoAppTree` by changing the `action` column to:

```
openDashboard('testing123')
```

and then hovering the mouse of the node to see if the above action appears in the JavaScript link, but that did not appear.

Can someone suggest how I can change the `Member Groups` link so that it opens a new page in dashboard please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my solution I have a custom LoadMemberGroups class, which replaces Umbraco's default loadMemberGroups class (I do this by editing the `umbracoAppTree` table and changing the `treeHandlerAssembly` and `treeHandlerType` columns for the existing `loadMemberGroups` entry).

I didn't realise that in my code I can set the `action` for the `Member Groups` node like this:

```
protected override void CreateRootNode(ref XmlTreeNode rootNode)
{
    rootNode.Action = "MyAction";
}
```

So I can change the action to whatever I need. Cool.